# How to make label and input text inline

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a pagination to my table.

I need the label with text "of 30" inline with the input text.

How could I do that?

Here is the link on Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uwom05mc/2/

//MARKUP

```
<nav>
        <ul class="pagination" style="margin: 0px !important;">
         <li><a href >First</a>
         </li><li><a href>&lt;</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a>
             <input type="text" class="select-page form-control" id="pagenav" class="form-control">
             <label>of 30</label>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li><a href>&gt;</a>
         </li><li><a href>Last</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting `display: inline-block` on `#pagenav` in order to have the text display next to the input, you also need to adjust the heights and margins of the containing elements:

```
#pagenav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagination>li>a {
  height: 34px;
}

.pagination li a input {
  height: 26px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

I've created an updated fiddle showcasing this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/fkvsx5mj/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```css
#pagenav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Mr Dan, Thank you.  It solves my problem of inline. But, now I see the height of "li" containing the input text is too big in relation to others .May you tell me how to fix it?